# VB.Net DGV + Pagination Issue

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, pagination

I have an SQLite DB with 1 million rows.  Obviously the DGV fails hard at displaying large amounts of records.  So I've implemented paging, where only 50k records are displayed at once.

This works, but I haven't found a solution if I want to do some processing/updating of all the data in the DB at once, I can only do it 50k records at a time.  Do I need to call GetPage for each chunk, do the processing, then move to the next page programmatically until their are none left?  I guess a DataReader would be appropriate?

Also, using pagination, if I select some rows from page 1, which contains 50k rows, I can't also select any rows from page 2 in my DGV, correct?

```
Private connString As String = "Data Source=data.s3db;Version=3"
Private dt As DataTable
Private pageNumber As Integer
Private pageSize As Integer = 50000
Private adapter As SQLiteDataAdapter

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    pageNumber += 1
    dt = GetPage(pageNumber * pageSize, pageSize)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    pageNumber -= 1
    dt = GetPage(pageNumber * pageSize, pageSize)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Public Function GetPage(startIndex As Integer, pageSize As Integer)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Using adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM test LIMIT " & pageSize & " OFFSET " & startIndex, connString)
        adapter.Fill(table)
    End Using
    Return table
End Function
```

Comment: You can fill the datatable incrementally, do whatever and then update all rows at once. Put it in a transaction and it should be fine performance wise.  You'll have to refactor that to not create a new DataAdapter for each page.

Comment: Note that paging (as with the Prev / Next buttons) is not the same as loading incrementally where the data accumulates.  For either method I would not use `LIMIT`; otherwise the only difference is whether you unload the previous 50k set each time (which conflicts with any sort of all-at-once ops)

Comment: @plutonix So to do the all-at-once ops, I need to have all the records loaded into my table?  I can do that incrementally to improve loading time, but the RAM usage of a DT with 1 million rows I'm going to have to deal with to get the functionality I'm looking for it seems.  What would the alternative to LIMIT be, if you don't mind me asking?  

Thanks for the responses BTW.

Comment: @plutonix I think I found another method instead of using LIMIT by calling a different overloaded method of SQLiteDataAdapter.Fill, like from here.  http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_paging.htm

I'll give that a try, it might have been closer to what you were suggesting.

Comment: I have several answers here doing paging and batches but of course I cant find them now.  But yes, there is an overload to tell it how many rows and a starting point similar to your `GetPage` method.  You'll almost certainly want to use a single persistent dataadapter though

Comment: @Plutonix Appreciate the help very much, I think you set me on the right path.